# How to get a file descriptor using a file name inside a system call in Linux

Tags: linux, file, call, system

I am creating a system call in sys.c file in Linux. I want to  get a file descriptor using a file name. I remember I can do it by using open system call. However, inside a system call, how can I use open system call to get a file descriptor (I remember I cannot call a system call inside a system call) or is there another way to get the file descriptor? Thank you.